# Vertical Scroll only on Ipad with jScroll. Need to stop this

Tags: jquery

I am using jscroll at the following site:

[skalko.peterfreedman.com](http://skalko.peterfreedman.com)

Works great - however on the ipad - you can move your finger up and the table move up and down vertically. I want to lock the vertical position on the ipad so this does not happen. Any thoughts would be appreciated.